# how to solve propositional logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Boolean variables A,B,C, and D are all independent of each other. P(a) = 0.22, P(b) = 0.47, P(c)= 0.82, and P(d) = 0.59. Given this, find the following probabilities.

$ P((A \ \lor \sim C) \to (B \land D)) $

I got stuck with this I'm not sure how to simplify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\bigl(a \lor \lnot c) \to (b \land d)\bigr)\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&\lnot (a \lor \lnot c) \lor  (b \land d)\qquad\text{[since $p \to q \equiv \lnot p \lor q$]}\\[4pt]
\equiv\;&(\lnot a \land c) \lor  (b \land d)
\qquad\;\;\,\text{[by DeMorgan's law]}\\[4pt]
&\;\;\text{hence}\\[4pt]
\;\;&P(\bigl(a \lor \lnot c) \to (b \land d)\bigr)\\[4pt]
=\;&P\bigl((\lnot a \land c) \lor  (b \land d)\bigr)\\[4pt]
=\;&
P(\lnot a \land c)
+P(b \land d)
-P\bigl((\lnot a \land c) \land  (b \land d)\bigr)\\[4pt]
=\;&
P(\lnot a \land c)
+P(b \land d)
-P(\lnot a \land c \land b \land d)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
But it's given that $a,b,c,d$ are independent.

Can you finish it?

Comment: can you help me with the complete solution?

Comment: If $x,y$ are independent, then $P(x \land y) = P(x)P(y)$, so for example,
$$P(\lnot a \land c) = P(\lnot a)P(c) = (1-P(a))P(c) = (.78)(.82)$$

Comment: yup got it thanks a lot :)